# Vba code for addinf information to a cell which loation is asked from the user

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find solution for my code, where first the user is asked a player's name and then the macro searches for the name in my database. If the name is there then the macro asks how many goals the player has made.
Then the number of goals written to the inputBox is added to the player's information.

My problem is that the macro doesn't add the number of goals for the player that has been searched.

Here is my code right now:

```
Sub goals()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")


 Dim etsi As String
 etsi = InputBox("Etsi Jäsen", "maalien lisääminen") 'asking the player and finding it


If Trim(etsi) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Data").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=etsi, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

   tulos = InputBox("Anna pelaajan maalienmäärä", "maalien lisääminen")
     Range(Rng).Value = "teksti"         'asks the goals and adds them to the player this is my problem area


        Else
                MsgBox "Jäsentä ei löytynyt"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Excel informs that I have run time error 1004.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `Rng` already refers to a range object, so you don't have to enclose it such as: `Range(Rng).Value = "teksti"`. Instead, write `Rng.Value = "teksti"`.

Of course, the code above it going to literally write the word "teksti" into the cell that `Rng` points to. I'm not exactly sure what you want to do there, but let us know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: if i have the rng.Value it adds the number of goals but in the wrong place. The number of goals are now added to replace the name and i want them to another colum on my data sheet